# How to search and highlight text in HTML page from varies elements (not just one) using vanilla javascript?

Tags: javascript, search, text, find

I want to search for text, word, or letter, using a search bar on my webpage, which highlights the word I searched or letter on the page, I saw a tutorial for the same but they use only one element (for example one paragraph with text in it), my problem that I have several elements and there is text in them?

I all looking for the code in vanilla javascript that would solve my issue.

```
        <div>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." onblur="search()">
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

example 1:
[How to highlight text when entering into input search bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70320389/how-to-highlight-text-when-entering-into-input-search-bar)

example 2:
[How to highlight text using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644428/how-to-highlight-text-using-javascript)

```js
const searchHighlighter = (elem, that) => {
        let el = document.getElementsByClassName(elem);
        for (let i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
          el[i].innerHTML = el[i].innerText.replace(new RegExp(that.value + "(?!([^<]+)?<)", "gi"), "<mark>$&</mark>");
        }
      };
```

```html
 <input id="searchInput" onkeyup="searchHighlighter('el', this)" placeholder="Type here" />

    <div class="el">Type in input and see the result! Now type TYPE word to see multi highlight of same word</div>
    <div class="el">Type in input and see the result! Now type TYPE word to see multi highlight of same word</div>
```